# Sharing violation on path /data/user/0/....Android/files/currentlog.txt

Tags: file, xamarin, stream

I am simply trying to append some contents to my log file and I keep receiving this, sometimes there never is an issue and then hell break lose and I start getting those sharing violations with no code changes, just restarting the app.

```
    public static async void appendfile(IFile file, string contents)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadAndWrite).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                stream.Seek(stream.Length, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    await sw.WriteAsync(contents).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            ADAKGlobal.processexception(exc, "ADAKFile.appendfile=" + file.Name + ", contents(50)=" + contents.Substring(0,50));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suspect you start writing to the file before another time is done which is causing the access violation

Comment: I understand, so what should I do then?

Comment: Serilog https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-xamarin

Comment: or SQLite db or write to some analytics framework

Comment: So Ken, you cannot see anything wrong with my code huh?